# How do I selectively change variable data type automatically in the tidyverse?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to change some of the variables from numerical to factor types, leaving other types as they are. I know how to do this one variable at a time, but I would like to automate the process for larger datasets.

I've changed variables in the `mtcars` dataset one by one, copying and pasting the code. I've used `mapply` to successfully automate this, but I've only managed to do it on a subset of `mtcars`. I'm not sure how I would keep the entire dataset intact with the new variable types, though. Reprex below.

```r
#before

as_tibble(mtcars)
#> # A tibble: 32 x 11
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#>  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#>  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#>  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#> # ... with 22 more rows

#copy + paste job

mtcars$cyl <- factor(as.character(mtcars$cyl))
mtcars$hp <- factor(as.character(mtcars$hp))
mtcars$vs <- factor(as.character(mtcars$vs))

#after

as_tibble(mtcars)
#> # A tibble: 32 x 11
#>      mpg cyl    disp hp     drat    wt  qsec vs       am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21   6      160  110    3.9   2.62  16.5 0         1     4     4
#>  2  21   6      160  110    3.9   2.88  17.0 0         1     4     4
#>  3  22.8 4      108  93     3.85  2.32  18.6 1         1     4     1
#>  4  21.4 6      258  110    3.08  3.22  19.4 1         0     3     1
#>  5  18.7 8      360  175    3.15  3.44  17.0 0         0     3     2
#>  6  18.1 6      225  105    2.76  3.46  20.2 1         0     3     1
#>  7  14.3 8      360  245    3.21  3.57  15.8 0         0     3     4
#>  8  24.4 4      147. 62     3.69  3.19  20   1         0     4     2
#>  9  22.8 4      141. 95     3.92  3.15  22.9 1         0     4     2
#> 10  19.2 6      168. 123    3.92  3.44  18.3 1         0     4     4
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

I managed to change the variable types successfully. I would hate to do this something like 30-50 times though. What are some ways to automate this? Thank you.

Comment: `mutate_if(is.factor,as.character)` or use `mutate_at`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is `mutate_at`.  The `as.factor(as.character` is not needed, we can directly convert to `factor`.  But, the reverse route would be `factor -> character -> numeric)

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
     as_tibble %>%
     mutate_at(vars(cyl, hp, vs), factor)
# A tibble: 32 x 11
#     mpg cyl    disp hp     drat    wt  qsec vs       am  gear  carb
#   <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  21   6      160  110    3.9   2.62  16.5 0         1     4     4
# 2  21   6      160  110    3.9   2.88  17.0 0         1     4     4
# 3  22.8 4      108  93     3.85  2.32  18.6 1         1     4     1
# 4  21.4 6      258  110    3.08  3.22  19.4 1         0     3     1
# 5  18.7 8      360  175    3.15  3.44  17.0 0         0     3     2
# 6  18.1 6      225  105    2.76  3.46  20.2 1         0     3     1
# 7  14.3 8      360  245    3.21  3.57  15.8 0         0     3     4
# 8  24.4 4      147. 62     3.69  3.19  20   1         0     4     2
# 9  22.8 4      141. 95     3.92  3.15  22.9 1         0     4     2
#10  19.2 6      168. 123    3.92  3.44  18.3 1         0     4     4
# … with 22 more rows
```

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, to reverse the process, we follow:

 mutate_at(vars(), numeric) -> mutate_at(vars(), character) -> mutate_at(vars(), factor).

Is this correct?

Comment: @ChrisAguilar  It would be `mutate_at(vars(cyl, hp, vs), list(~ as.numeric(as.character(.))))`

Answer (score 6):

```
library(dplyr)

as_tibble(mtcars) %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(cyl, hp, vs),
            .funs = ~ factor(as.character(.)))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Using base R:

```
vars_to_make_f <- c("cyl", "hp", "vs")
mtcars[vars_to_make_f] <- 
  lapply(mtcars[vars_to_make_f], function(x) as.factor(as.character(x)))

mtcars
# A tibble: 32 x 11
     mpg cyl    disp hp     drat    wt  qsec vs       am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  21   6      160  110    3.9   2.62  16.5 0         1     4     4
 2  21   6      160  110    3.9   2.88  17.0 0         1     4     4
 3  22.8 4      108  93     3.85  2.32  18.6 1         1     4     1
 4  21.4 6      258  110    3.08  3.22  19.4 1         0     3     1
 5  18.7 8      360  175    3.15  3.44  17.0 0         0     3     2
 6  18.1 6      225  105    2.76  3.46  20.2 1         0     3     1
 7  14.3 8      360  245    3.21  3.57  15.8 0         0     3     4
 8  24.4 4      147. 62     3.69  3.19  20   1         0     4     2
 9  22.8 4      141. 95     3.92  3.15  22.9 1         0     4     2
10  19.2 6      168. 123    3.92  3.44  18.3 1         0     4     4
# ... with 22 more rows
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mutate_at`:

```
 mtcars %>% 
 mutate_at(c("cyl","hp","vs"),function(x) factor(as.character(x)))
```

Or use `purrr` `modify_at`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  modify_at(c("cyl","hp","vs"),function(x) factor(as.character(x)))
```